# Adding all values for certain dates and the following day

Tags: sql-server-2012, window-functions

I am trying to do some reporting to see if an event drove sales on the day after the event as well. So for this I am trying to add all the sales from the day of an event and the day after it for each set of data. It does not matter which store the sale happened for the purpose of this report. However it is possible to have a day appear up to 22 times (1 for each store). All the data is stored in one table called UCS.

I have tried finding a way to make Lag or Lead work using case statements and temp tables but so far no luck.

Below are a couple of screenshots to help show what I am trying to do. I need to add the sales marked yellow for each screenshot.

You will notice in example 2 I am not adding the values from the days 11/4 or 11/13. While those are the next date in the data set they are not the next day on the calendar.

Example1

[image: Example1]

Example 2

[image: Example2]

Comment: For future questions, please do NOT use images of data as they are not re-usable. It is preferred if you just paste formatted tables  e.g. https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/  (why? just imagine if answers came as images of queries )

Comment: Thank you I was not sure how to do the formatted tables.

Answer (score 0):

Moments after posting this my brain clicked and figured it out. I can make a temp table pulling in a list of dates where there is an event doing a union to a list of dates equal to the dates of event +1 using a date table that just houses the dates of the calendar. Then use this to join back and limit the original table. Sample code below to better explain.

```
If OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Event')   IS NOT NULL     DROP TABLE #Event

Select *
Into #Event
From (
Select
     Universal_ID
    ,Date

From UCS

Where   Month = 11
    and Year = 2018
    and Event = 1

Union

Select
     Universal_ID
    ,DL.Date

From UCS
    Join DateLookup as DL
        on DATEADD(d,1,UCS.Date) = DL.Date

Where   UCS.Month = 11
    and UCS.Year = 2018
    and Event = 1
) as A


Select
    Sum(Sale) as Sale

From UCS
    Join #Event as E
        on UCS.Universal_ID = E.Universal_ID
            and UCS.date = E.date

Where   Month = 11
    and Year = 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a universal set of dates for this, if the date isn't in the UCS table it will not matter to the end result

```
select
    sum(sale)
from UCS t
inner join (
    select date from UCS where event = 1
    union
    select dateadd(day,1,date) from UCS where event = 1
    ) d on t.date = d.date
```

You can avoid a union in the subquery which may help avoid a pass through the UCS table by using a cross join, but this might not be worthwhile - only assessing execution plans would reveal this:

```
select
    sum(sale)
from UCS t
inner join (
    select distinct dateadd(day,cj.n,date) as date
    from UCS
    cross join (select 0 as n union all select 1) cj
    where event = 1
    ) d on t.date = d.date
;
```